# Largest number of edges IF graph has more than one connected component

Tags: graph-theory

For a algorithms final review, this question came up:

```
For a Graph G with V vertices and E edges, what is the largest number of edges 
this graph can have IF there are more than one connected components within G
```

Since a connected component is essentially a graph within a graph, that means all vertices within the subgraph must be removed from the larger graph while remaining internally connective.  I can understand the intuition, but am having a hard time converting it into a formula.

Here's what I've come up with so far:

For connected component n, each graph Gn has a corresponding vertex set {Vn} such that the contents of the vertex set are internally connected, while remaining externally disconnected.

```
Graph G1 = {V1}
Graph G2 = {V2}
    ...
Graph Gn = {Vn}
```

Now, each {Vn} contains a maximum of V * (V-1) edges.

How can I express the maximum number of edges using a formula?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's a multi-graph (with self-loops and parallel edges), then of course any number of edges is possible, but I believe this is about graphs where edges are defined as undirected non-reflexive edges.

In that case each component of K nodes can have at most `k* (k-1)` edges. Since this is of quadratic nature The greatest number of edges you can achieve is if you have one giant component and one minimal component. So just two components with N-1 and 1 elements, each.

This graph would have `( N - 1 ) * ((N - 1) - 1) = (N - 1) * (N - 2) = (N^2 -3N +2)` edges, which I believe is the formula for the maximum number of edges in a graph with more than one component.